# Show my posts as well as followers posts in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to make a homepage somewhat like Facebook, I made it so it could show the posts from the people I follow, but I couldn't see my own posts as I can't  follow myself. Here is the line of SQL code I've written (it contains PHP variables):

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_posts 
INNER JOIN user_following ON user_posts.username = user_following.username 
WHERE user_following.follower = '$me->username' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0, 15
```

1. The `user_posts` table contains all the posts.
2. The `user_following` table contains all follow data, where `username` is the user being followed, and the `follower` is the user following the `username`
3. `$me->username` is the username of the user logged in.

`user_posts` table structure:
[image]

`user_following` table structure:
[image]

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: `mysql_*` methods are long-since deprecated. Please use PDO or `mysqli_*` methods.

Comment: I have to use `mysql` as the website I'm working on is using `mysql`

Comment: I'm guessing you should use a `LEFT JOIN` and add an `OR user_posts.what_field_holds_username = '$me->username'` to your `WHERE` clause. Also note that `*` brings back every column for both the predicate and joined tables, so name collisions could be an issue.

Comment: The code above only shows the posts of the people I follow, but I want to make it show both, my posts aswell as the posts the people I follow

Comment: Another solution would be to add in a `user_following` entry for everyone, so they follow themselves. You don't have to show that in the UI if you don't want to - and it may simplify your queries.

Comment: Right. You're only joining to get the relationship. Start with a query to get *your* posts, *then* join to get the referred ones, but use a join type that doesn't exclude (`LEFT` instead of `INNER` generally).

Comment: @halfer - Altering a query in a simple way is much easier, IMO, than adding a self-reference, then having to write code to ignore that reference in various places.

Comment: @Jared: you may be right, but I'd still recommend to the OP that they benchmark both approaches. If the `INNER` changes to an `OUTER` here, or the query gets more complex, then it may slow down the site unacceptably. Of course, this may all be dreadfully premature optimisation, but I would rather the OP think about it and reject it explicitly than kick themselves later for not considering it.

Comment: I changed the code to: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_posts LEFT JOIN user_following ON user_posts.username = user_following.username
WHERE user_following.follower = '$me->username' OR user_posts.username = '$me->username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 15")` but it just messes up the homepage

Comment: @Arqetech: readers will frequently ask for precise language here. "Messes up the homepage" is not a bug report `:-)`. Do you get a SQL error? Is the HTML output producing too many/few rows? etc.

Comment: @Arqetech, mysql_* functions are deprecated. You must use mysqli_* functions or PDO to work with yout MySQL database.

Comment: @Arqetech - Here's an example sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e97c/4 You'll want to work a way around the `GROUP BY`, which is caused by your `JOIN` to `user_following` (you'll get more than one row back when there's a row in both). What you might do is start with your `users` table, then join to `user_following`, then to `user_posts` from there.

Comment: Somewhat different method: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bf2c6/1

Comment: @JaredFarrish I changed your sqlfiddle to this: `SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user_posts.username = '$me->username' OR user_posts.username IN(SELECT username follower FROM user_following WHERE user_following.follower = '$me->username') GROUP BY user_posts.id DESC LIMIT 0, 15` and it worked, Thanks! :)

Comment: Here's the other method I outlined, but it too requires summation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d91be/1

Comment: @Arqetech: please post your amended version of Jared's query as a separate answer - prepending the answer at the top of your original question is unnecessarily confusing for readers who did not see the original. Questions here are for posterity, and so should largely be preserved as they were asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to skin this query:

**Sub-query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_posts 
WHERE user_posts.username = 'bob'
OR user_posts.username IN(
  SELECT username 
  FROM user_following
  WHERE user_posts.username = user_following.username
)
LIMIT 0, 15
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bf2c6/9

**Use the Users Table**

Requires `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT user_posts.id`, which are non-optimal.

```
SELECT
   user_posts.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_following ON users.username = user_following.username
INNER JOIN user_posts ON (
  users.username = user_posts.username
  OR user_following.follower = user_posts.username
)
WHERE users.username = 'bob'
GROUP BY user_posts.id
LIMIT 0, 15
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d91be/1

**IMPORTANT!** Make sure and index those columns in your table. Otherwise, performance will suffer as the tables get bigger (especially `user_following`).

Comment: Considering that the OP did not provide a `CREATE TABLE` schema, and you had to make do with a screenshot, the Fiddles are great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select * 
from user_posts up 
join user_following uf on up.username = uf.username
where uf.follower = '$me->username'
or up.username = '$me->username'
```

Comment: if you could provide more informations about the tables structure it would be really easy.

Comment: Not my question - you can either await the OP providing it, or make an educated guess `:-)`

Comment: i have edited my Answer let me know if it did not work.